# Given username and password, how do I copy files from one machine to another using perl on windows

Tags: windows, perl

I main issue is of authentication, then the actual copying of files from once machine to another. By the way both these machines are on the same network i.e. connected through LAN.

Is there any perl function to do this. Plus, I wanted to make sure if authentication is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are two windows machines or if both have [samba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29) or [CIFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIFS) shares--below or at where you want to copy from/to, then you can just *map* or *mount* one onto the other machine and copy that way. The security depends on your network and how the shares were set up.

Also, in this vein, given the hostname or ip you might be able to use a UNC path:

```
\\remotehost\c$\Users\Me\Documents -- depending on your level of access
```

Otherwise there is [`Net::FTP`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aFTP) if you don't need SSL and [`Net::SCP`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSCP)/[`SFTP`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSFTP) if you do. You can often script these to do directory copies.